# RecordRTC is not working working in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend, recordrtc

I am using RecordRTC library in my project in nextjs, but it is showing error `node_modules/recordrtc/RecordRTC.js (1586:0) @ eval`

```
TypeError: Cannot set property navigator of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

My code is

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then((stream)=>{
          var options:{
            mimeType:"audio/wav",
            numberOfAudioChannels:1|2,
          } = {
            mimeType: "audio/wav",
            numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
            };
            let record = new RecordRTC(stream,options);
            record.startRecording();
            setRecordRtc(record);
        });
```

where mediaConstraints is

```
 let mediaConstraints = {
      video: false,
      audio: true
      };
```

I went to RecordRTC.js at 1586 line and i got

```
 global.navigator = {
        userAgent: browserFakeUserAgent,
        getUserMedia: function() {}
    };
```

I don't know what wrong i am doing, please help me.
Also i am doing client render in nextjs to render this component to use navigator, still i am getting this error.

I have tried looking for solution on its github lib . Also tried to see if there is error in this library with nextjs but no luck so far.